# Is there any way I can get .net stack traces in Sql Profiler, or a similar tool?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, profiling, profiler

In my previous job I designed and helped build a run-time(production) [Profiler tool](http://www.samsaffron.com/blog/archive/2007/05/11/15.aspx) that among other cool features was able to give me .Net stack traces for every SQL statement that executed. Think of it as SQL-Server Profiler on steroids. So instead of just seeing SQL statements and duration, you also got the context in which the SQL executed. When developing DB centric apps I find this information a god-send.

The problem is that since this was developed my previous company has been acquired by Symantec, though the tool is still downloadable , it is very unclear what the licensing is and it is not SKU Symnatec is selling.

I was wondering if anyone knows of any similar tools that will give me Stack Traces with my SQL statement executions?

[alt screenshot http://img151.imageshack.us/img151/4357/profiler1jz3.gif](http://img151.imageshack.us/img151/4357/profiler1jz3.gif)

This remains unanswered, ANTS et el do not do this, considering just answering no and accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if it will do excatly what you need but the best profiling tool i have found for .Net is [ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/Products/ants_profiler/index.htm), If i remember it will show you the SQL and also all the .net calls.

Answer (score 0):

We have recently starting a tool called [dynaTrace](http://www.dynatrace.com/en/).  There is a workstation verison that you can use on one box and a server/agent version for operating against many boxes.

Basically, you set up the tool against a particular application (or IIS).  After that it will collect method calls that it is instrumented against.  In your scenario you might instrument against entire namespaces and get everything.

Basically it then tracks every method call by using IL injection.  It picks up the database calls by instrumenting against ADO.Net including the bind variables in SP's.  It can apparently track across Web Service calls as well.

It is pretty cool in that you can look at specific methods, see all the paths that were made to call that method, or look at all calls to a method.  You can look at a specific database call, and look at all the code paths with that call.

It's pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

I've posted an answer here that brings together info from a couple of posts, plus an app that can be used as a poor mans query monitor for MySQL:

[How can I view live MySQL queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568564/how-can-i-view-live-mysql-queries/9398566#9398566)