# how trace database sdf file by sql server profiler

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-profiler, sdf

How can consider a sdf database file in App_Data Folder in visual studio in sql sever profiler?

I try to open file by File-> Open-> Trace File (below pic) but it doesn't accept  .sdf file
as trace file

http://www.mssqltips.com/tipimages2/2232_OpenTraceFile.png

Thanks for help

Comment: SQL Server Profiler only works on the full, server-based versions of SQL Server - it doesn't support SQL Server **Compact Edition** (which uses the `.sdf` file as database)

Comment: tnx @marc_s , you'r right. i also fine this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225121/profiler-for-sql-ce

Comment: While not a profiler, you might find this useful if you're using EF - there's an extension method for logging insert/update/delete statements to a CE database, about halfway down in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2a50ffd2-ed73-411d-82bc-c9c564623cb4/logging-sql-statements?forum=adodotnetentityframework).  Better than nothing at all.

Comment: dear @SandraWalters, thank you so much, yes i'm using ef. i read your link. it was helpful.