# DbCommand Insert error The syntax of the query near identifier 'INTO'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I really can't understand Why I get it "**The syntax of the query near identifier 'INTO'**"?

```
Ctx = new aiautodbEntities(connectionstring);
Ctx.Connection.Open();
    var comm = Ctx.Connection.CreateCommand();
                        comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ListUsers (u_name,u_personalnumber,u_login,u_pass,u_position,u_ugadn,u_ugadndata,u_serverId) values(@u_name,@u_personalnumber,@u_login,@u_pass,@u_position,@u_ugadn,@u_ugadndata,@u_serverId)";
                        comm.Parameters.Add(new EntityParameter(){ParameterName="u_name",Value= newUser.u_name});
...
                        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Even if i write

```
INSERT INTO ListUsers (u_name) values ('fdfdbf');
```

I have the same error.

I use `DbConnection, SqlCE, EntityFramework`

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225121/profiler-for-sql-ce). A kind of a profiler or query logging application should help you find the query being sent to the db.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO [ListUsers] ([u_name]) VALUES ('fdfdbf');
```

Comment: do not work =( [dbo].[ListUsers] not work too, @"INSERT INTO [ListUsers] ([u_name]) VALUES ('fdfdbf')" - not work too.

Comment: have added table schema

Comment: "The syntax of the query near identifier 'ListUsers'" Not sure that "try remove the INTO" - lead to the correct query