# Is there anyway to set mysql on IIS 7 with PHP5 to show all mysql queries performed? (or save to txt file)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm aware of **mysql_query("show processlist");** however what I need is a live feed of the queries being performed as I test my websites on localhost (IIS7+PHP5) on WINDOWS 7.

Why? Because I have to perform optimization on my poorly structured database and I want to identify all the queries and go through all of them, however my php scripts dynamically generates queries and it takes a long time to go through my hundreds of PHP files to add "error_log()" to all of the queries.

I basically want to view the queries live as they are running, or perhaps save them to a text file so I can view them. Perhaps there's a way to have an automatically refreshing list of "show processlist" inside command prompt?

Comment: If you don't absolutely need a "live view" of performed queries, then use MySQLs "general query log" by starting `mysqld` with a `--log=fn` 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

Comment: Might sound dumb, but I have no idea how to use that. I opened command prompt and typed mysqld --general-log="c:\users\me\desktop\test.txt" - I then went to my localhost site and tested and it didn't add any queries to test.txt -- what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of: [How can I view live MySQL queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568564/how-can-i-view-live-mysql-queries)

Check out the [General Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html)

Comment: On windows 7? I'm running on my localhost test machine.

Comment: I don't see why not.  How are you starting mysql?  As a windows service or manually from the command prompt?

Comment: @Joe You'll need to add those parameters to the service startup.  I'm not entirely sure where to do this, but somewhere under Control Panel and administration / services.