# PDO sends raw query to MySQL while Mysqli sends prepared query, both produce the same result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I started to know how prepared statement works when using MySQLi and PDO, for first step, I enabled MySQL query monitoring as mentioned here: [How can I view live MySQL queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568564/how-can-i-view-live-mysql-queries). Then I created the following test:

**Using mysqli:**

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username =?")) {
$stmt->bind_param("i", $user);
$user = "''1''";
```

**server logs:**

> ```
>   130802 23:39:39   175 Connect   ****@localhost on testdb
>     175 Prepare   SELECT * FROM users WHERE username =?
>     175 Execute   SELECT * FROM users WHERE username =0
>     175 Quit
> ```

**Using PDO:**

```
  $user = "''1''";
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid =?';
  $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
  $sth->bindParam(1, $user, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

**Server Logs:**

> ```
>   130802 23:41:42   176 Connect   ****@localhost on testdb
>     176 Query SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid ='\'\'1\'\''
>     176 Quit
> ```

**However, both provides same result:**

```
uid: 0
username: admin
role: admin
```

Note: `uid = 0` is correct because `intval("''1''") = 0`

What is important here:

#### How PDO query gets same result while it sends different query to MySQL?

`SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid ='\'\'1\'\''`

I found only one indication from PHP Manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

> Note:
>
> Emulated prepared statements does not communicate with the database
>   server so PDO::prepare() does not check the statement.

But I am not sure How MySQL deals with this query and substitute `'\'\'1\'\''` with `0`. At that case monitoring queries will not be accurate if using PDO, at same time, using PDO is better for knowing exact queries that sent to MySQL but not MySQLi.

**Update:** 
after changing parameter type frm integer to string:

MySQLi Log:

> ```
>     188 Prepare   SELECT * FROM awa_user WHERE username =?
>     188 Execute   SELECT * FROM awa_user WHERE username ='\'\'1\'\''
>     188 Quit
> ```

PDO Log:

> ```
>     189 Query SELECT * FROM awa_user WHERE userame ='\'\'1\'\''
>     189 Quit
> ```

This means that MySQLi and PDO escaping the data before sending to MySQL when using string, while for integers, mysqli applies intval() or something like that before sending the query, as also answered by Bill which is correct.

Comment: How is this related to prepared statements?

Comment: Ìn the first code snippet, why do you set `$user` to `''1''`? When you bind it you use `i` (integer). When you then set `$user` to `''1''` MySQL probably does not recognize it as a number and just sets it to 0 (zero).

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: I assumed that an attacker enters this value, I want to see the query log how it sent to MySQL, consider any data that `$user` will be...

Comment: @YourCommonSense: this core of understanding of prepared statement, this how in deep it works, what is not clear, I can explain. Also, see how wrong result returned if still using wrong keyword for search, this indicates that validating user input before executing any  query is important.

Comment: Your question is how mysql evaluates `''1''` string in raw query. Pretty usual question on loose type casting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your PDO is configured to emulate prepared queries, whereas mysqli is using true prepared queries.

The prepared query binds the string `''1''` as an integer parameter value.  PHP coerces it to an integer using something like `intval()`.  Any string with non-numeric leading characters is  interpreted as 0 by PHP, so the parameter value sent *after* prepare is the value 0.

The fake prepared query uses *string interpolation* (instead of binding) to add the string `''1''` into the SQL query *before* MySQL parses it.  But the result is similar, because SQL also treats a string with non-numeric leading characters in an integer context as the value 0.

The only difference is what ends up in the general query log when the parameter is bound before prepare versus after prepare.

You can also make PDO use real prepared queries, so it should act just like mysqli in this case:

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

PS: This may demonstrate a good reason why it's customary to start id values at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: `But the result is similar, because SQL also treats a string with non-numeric leading characters in an integer context as the value 0.` exactly what I realized experimentally, you are clever...

Comment: I got an anonymous downvote.  Please, downvoter, leave a comment to tell me know how this question isn't satisfactory.  Maybe I can improve it.

Comment: I got also one but not here, for an answer that was before 3 days, forget it :)

Comment: @BillKarwin welcome to PDO tag. Nearly all answers here get downvoted by the PDO police.