# Entity Framework - Stored Procedure with Multiple results sets - no rows return

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

so, i was trying to implement a stored procedure with multiple results sets in entity framework.
it all seemed to be too easy.
but, i am not getting any rows for my results sets (even though, it seems i do get the result sets themselves back).

What i have done:

1. created the stored procedure which returns 3 result sets
2. Created the complex type that represents the return values
3. manually edited the edmx file as per [Stored Procedures with Multiple Result Sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx)
4. Failed with 3 and tried the code version from the same page, still no rows back.
5. Reverted the code back to 3.

my edmx file (related content only):

```
  <FunctionImport Name="getGlobalReport2">
    <ReturnType Type="Collection(MTModel.GlobalReport2)"/>
    <ReturnType Type="Collection(MTModel.GlobalReport2)"/>
    <ReturnType Type="Collection(MTModel.GlobalReport2)"/>
    <Parameter Name="regions" Mode="In" Type="String" />
    <Parameter Name="countries" Mode="In" Type="String" />
    <Parameter Name="companySizes" Mode="In" Type="String" />
    <Parameter Name="products" Mode="In" Type="String" />
  </FunctionImport>

  <FunctionImportMapping FunctionImportName="getGlobalReport2" FunctionName="MTModel.Store.getGlobalReport2" >
    <ResultMapping>
      <ComplexTypeMapping TypeName="MTModel.GlobalReport2" />
    </ResultMapping>
    <ResultMapping>
      <ComplexTypeMapping TypeName="MTModel.GlobalReport2" />
    </ResultMapping>
    <ResultMapping>
      <ComplexTypeMapping TypeName="MTModel.GlobalReport2" />
    </ResultMapping>
  </FunctionImportMapping>
```

my code:

```
var x = mtEntities.getGlobalReport2(regions, countries, companySizes, products);
Response.Write(x.Count());

var y = x.GetNextResult<GlobalReport2>();
Response.Write(y.Count());

var z = x.GetNextResult<GlobalReport2>();
```

What i have allready checked:

1. Checked that the server receives the request as per [How can I view live MySQL queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568564/how-can-i-view-live-mysql-queries)
2. Run the query i grabbed from the server and made sure it returns result sets and rows
3. Debug the app to see there are no Exceptions i missed on the way

There seems to be no issue with the call, or the app, except that no rows are returned.
Any suggestions?

EDIT:
as per your comments about the `edmx` being overwritten, that would happen only if i regenerate the model from the database, not if i update it.
i wouldn't expect anything else, since its regenerating the model.

Comment: Do you have to use the EDMX file? If it's regenerated you're going to lose to customizations.

Comment: i don't HAVE to use it, but that still does not solve the issue at hand.

Comment: I just realized this was MySQL, not MSSQL, but I recently made this work with MSSQL using the "Accessing Multiple Result Sets with Code" section at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx.

Answer (score 4):

Dont you think you should have some property defined for your complex types you have created ? For example:

```
<FunctionImportMapping FunctionImportName="GetGrades" 
                       FunctionName="SchoolModel.Store.GetGrades" >
  <ResultMapping>
    <ComplexTypeMapping TypeName="SchoolModel.GradeInfo">
      <ScalarProperty Name="EnrollmentID" ColumnName="enroll_id"/>
      <ScalarProperty Name="CourseID" ColumnName="course_id"/>
      <ScalarProperty Name="StudentID" ColumnName="student_id"/>
      <ScalarProperty Name="Grade" ColumnName="grade"/>
    </ComplexTypeMapping>
  </ResultMapping>
</FunctionImportMapping>
```

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716730%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) too

*Also as rightly stated by Mike in the comment to your question, if you in future update your edmx file, if it's regenerated you're going to lose to customizations.*

Comment: this is interesting, in the article i have added, they say nothing about this and since i do have access to those properties it seemed like they already mapped mapped since the complex type already exist