# MSSQL store procedure is executing twice in PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, zend-framework, pdo

I have this block of code which getting executed twice
when the post hits from the payment gateway.Any help will be welcome
on this issue. I have already checked the code there is no 404 resuest
to any script.

```
$stmt = $dbAdapter->prepare('EXEC MyProcedure  ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?');
$stmt->bindParam(1,$id,  PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(2,$Transaction,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(3,$Person_id,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(4,$Amount);
$stmt->bindParam(5,$OrderID,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(6,$BankClientID,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(7,$Transaction_Time,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(8,$status, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$id = $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: This piece of code cannot be executed twice... your error must be in another part

Comment: I handle the post from payment gateway . As soon as post hit i parse,prepare and execute the store procedure on a zend Framework 1 Application. But when the data goes in the database i see two entries

Comment: I even had checked with static fiels as well but it is still executing twice

Comment: I agree with Sal00m. Do a simple check to see if PHP executes the code twice, and therefore you get 2 entries in the database. Many gateways send multiple messages, in my experience.

Comment: If you can't find why it's doing that, as a last resort, you can set your affected column(s) as UNIQUE. Check to see if you're not including the file twice somewhere.

Comment: Thanks KIKO,Fred for your tips.I will check that

Comment: You're welcome. Have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-tracing-mysql.html and http://stackoverflow.com/q/568564/ and http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/database/monitor-all-sql-queries-in-mysql/?PageSpeed=noscript - Found those while Googling "trace mysql" if you wish to further your research, *cheers*