# How do I properly delete in Java mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, prepared-statement, sql-delete

I am at wits end with a Java web app that will not run a delete in Mysql. I get no errors, and when I copy and paste my query into the Mysql workbench, it does what it is supposed to. `SELECT` and `INSERT` both work for this table in my code.
Here is my code:

```
public void deleteParticipant(String email){
        try{
            connect();
            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(
                "DELETE FROM activity_connections WHERE user_email=? AND activity_id=? LIMIT 1"
            );
            pst.setString(1, email);
            pst.setString(2, this.id);
            pst.executeUpdate();
            pst.close();
            conn.close();
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException ce){
            System.out.println("Driver error: " + ce);
            ce.printStackTrace();
        }catch(SQLException se){
            System.out.println("SQL error: " + se);
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And here is the connect method

```
protected static Connection conn;
public static String CONNECTION_STRING = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/kokosole?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
public static String USERNAME = "root";
public static String PASSWORD = "password123";
protected static void connect() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = CONNECTION_STRING;
    Class.forName(driver);
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
}
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Add `conn.commit()`?

Comment: And use [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to properly manage your resources - you're in danger of leaving the connection open if something goes wrong

Comment: @KellyMarchewa The connection is set to autocommit

Comment: When you tested the query in MySQL Workbench were you connected using the same user as what you're connecting with in your code? Have you tried using a DELETE statement without a WHERE clause (with a test database, of course)? In the `activity_connections` table, is the `activity_id` a string or a number? Your code treats it as a string.

Comment: @Emmanuel Rosa I was connected as root user both for Mysql work bench and the Java app. I did not try delete without `WHERE`, but I used `WHERE 1=1`. `activity_id` is indeed a string.

Comment: print the value of `this.id`

Comment: You may want to start logging the queries to see what's going on. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568564/how-can-i-view-live-mysql-queries

Comment: @Riad I already printed and copied the query into Sal server to see if it would work and it did. I even ran a select statement with the same constraints and got the result I wanted.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa I logged the queries and `DELETE` is not even showing up.

Comment: OK, it looks like you have some traction now, Issac. At this point your issue requires troubleshooting, something we can't do because we don't have your computer. You should be trying things to answer questions such as "Is it just DELETE statements which are not executing?" Continue to narrow it down and come back when your have a more specific issue.

Comment: As I said earlier, I have been able to use `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, and `SELECT` just fine.